# How do I separate windows per workspace in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, application-switcher

I came from Ubuntu 14.04 where the windows were kept separated in their own workspace:

- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> used to show only windows active on current workspace
- Side Bar (Unity Launcher) used to show only windows active on current workspace

Now, in 18.04, all windows are merged in one single view when <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> is executed. How can I revert it to previous behavior?